# Directive not updateing (re-render) with data change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't get my angularJS module to update when the provider keeping the data is updated.
The console.logs are being written out, but html doesn't update.

**Directive**:

```
.directive('logBar', ['loggingService', function(loggingService) {
        var template = '<div class="floatLeft" ><div class="arrow"></div></div>' +
                '<ul class="floatLeft">' +
                '<li class="logHolder" tabindex="-1" ng-repeat="log in logs | reverse">' +
                '<label class="label label-{{log.type}}" ng-click="alert(log.message);" tabindex="-1">{{log.date | date:"HH:mm, dd.MMM" }} -  {{log.message}}</label>' +
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: template,
            scope: {},
            link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(function() {
                    console.log("logs updating");
                    $scope.logs = loggingService.getLogs();
                    console.log($scope.logs);
                });

           }
    };
}]);
```

**provider:**

```
provider('loggingService', function() {
    var logs = [{"date": Date.now(), "origin": "Logbar", "message": "Welcome", "type": "info"}];

    var maxLogs = 15;
    var types = "default,primary,success,info,warning,danger";
    this.resetLog = function() {
        logs = [];
    };
    this.Removelog = function(message, type, alert) {

    };
    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            logs: logs,
            getLogs: function() {
                return logs;
            },
            log: function(message, type, alert) {
                if (types.indexOf(type) === -1) {
                    if (type !== "error") {
                        type = "default";
                    } else {
                        type = "danger";
                    }
                }
                logs.push({"message": message, "type": type, "date": Date.now(), origin: "User"});
                if (logs.length > maxLogs) {
                    logs.shift();
                }
            }
        };
    };
})
```

**controller**:

Works with applys, but without them, it does not. Is there anyway to insert the $apply into the provider so I don't have to write them everywhere?

```
$http.post("/competition/" + $scope.key, angular.toJson($scope.draws)).success(function(data) {
            $scope.fixDraws();
            loggingService.log("Saved", "success", false);
            $scope.$apply();
        }).error(function(data) {
            loggingService.log("Error", "danger", true);
            $scope.fixDraws();
            $scope.$apply();
        });
```

Comment: Post `getLogs` code. I assume that the problem is *how* you load the data.

Comment: added provider with getLogs :-)

Comment: @dfsq It's here now :-)

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue with simplified [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2DUUIHUNqk1sxiYnAqr?p=preview). If you can set up a failing demo, it would help.

Comment: I've also just tried setting things up just like your example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wtOg2ZhCGAjd1uhKXrHR?p=preview), which works just fine..

Comment: I've found out that it's because i add logs from http calls. Can i do an $apply anywhere in the provider instead of every http call?

Comment: I can't spot any calls to `$apply` in the link you've posted?

Comment: I've added the controller where the $apply is :)

Comment: Updating my plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wtOg2ZhCGAjd1uhKXrHR?p=preview) to use `$http` rather than `$timeout` changes nothing. Have you been able to either figure the issue out, or create a demo where it's not working?

Comment: Afraid i have not been able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read, you're trying to update your scope from the `watchExpression`, not from the $watch `listener`.

Try this:

```
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(
                // watch expression
                function() {
                    return loggingService.getLogs();
                },
                // listener
                function(newVal){
                    $scope.logs = newVal;
                }
            );

       }
```

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: No, this can't be a problem. The only important part is `$scope.logs = loggingService.getLogs();` and it's executed anyway.

Comment: dfsq: do you mean to say that since the watch expression is always called before the listener then although it is not exactly used by the book here it would still work?

Comment: I'm saying that watch is not important part here at all. See http://plnkr.co/edit/t2DUUIHUNqk1sxiYnAqr?p=preview

Comment: Still it would seem to me that original code does not use $watch the proper way but I get your point. In this case that is not the problem.

Comment: Yea, @dfsq is right, here's a plunk where the original implementation works just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/wtOg2ZhCGAjd1uhKXrHR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by adding the `$apply` to the http calls. And I could not reproduce the error in another project.